# Why these regex find nothing? Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

code which I tested on https://regex101.com/

```
</tbody></table>
    <br /><span class="answer"><span class="answer"><br /></span></span>
```

regex applied:

```
<\/td><\/tr>
```

JS found nothing.

Another text:

```
<table
```

regex:

```
/<table /gi
```

JS found nothing.

```
<span class="answer"><span class="answer"><br /></span>
```

These two regexes I tried:
1. `/<span class="answer"><span class="answer"><br \/><\/span>/gi`
2. `/<span class="answer"><span class="answer">/gi`

JS found nothing.Why is it and how to correct?

Comment: please add the wanted result from matching.

Comment: `JS found nothing` Cauze there are no matches in provided string?

Answer (score 2):

Your simple regex patterns work, I suppose that the trouble was is input string(check if it properly formatted in your js code)

```
var str = '</tbody></table>\n <br /><span class="answer"><span class="answer"><br /></span></span>';

var pattern = /<span class="answer"><span class="answer"><br \/><\/span>/gi;
var pattern2 = /<span class="answer"><span class="answer">/gi;

var matches = str.match(pattern);
var matches2 = str.match(pattern2);

console.log(matches);   // ["<span class="answer"><span class="answer"><br /></span>"]
console.log(matches2);   // ["<span class="answer"><span class="answer">"]
```

Comment: I added a wider code into my question to explain how I am using the patterns. They are defined in array hArray and then I use method 
          `.replace( hArray[k], k );` to replace html tags. So it seems the problem is that I have error here instead hArray[k] should be hArray[k][*index*] ... but in that case, some patterns maybe could stop working. What exactly happens if only 1 result found or more results? Some tags were replaced correctly but none of those which I have posted here. Was it because of missing [*index*]?

Comment: Thanks all for answers. I accepted your answer. I still solve the problem with regex, but I created better question fitting .replace() problem

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is on the right side of that tester:

```
/<\/td><\/tr>/
< matches the characters < literally
\/ matches the character / literally
td>< matches the characters td>< literally (case sensitive)
\/ matches the character / literally
tr> matches the characters tr> literally (case sensitive)
```

so you are matching:

```
</td<>/tr>
```

but you do not have that string in:

```
</tbody></table>
    <br /><span class="answer"><span class="answer"><br /></span></span>
```

Second regex /

```
No match groups were extracted.

This means that your pattern matches but there were no (capturing (groups)) in it that matched anything in the subject string.
```

This will work:

```
 /(<table )/gi
```

Third regex:

```
<span class="answer"><span class="answer"><br /></span>
```

Has errors:

```
Errors are explained from left to right. Move the mouse cursor over them to see the error highlighted in your pattern
/ Unescaped delimiter
/ Unescaped delimiter
```

Fourth regex:

```
<span class="answer"><span class="answer">
```

is matching but again:

```
No match groups were extracted.
This means that your pattern matches but there were no (capturing (groups)) in it that matched anything in the subject string.
```

This works:

```
(<span class="answer"><span class="answer">)
```

I used the same regex tester as you.

Regards

Comment: sorry I wrong copied the lines from editor. Never mind. You wrote `so you are matching: </td<>/tr>` but this doesn't make sense to me coz the wrote these characters are matching litterally: < then / then td>< then / then tr> so the found item should be </td></tr> is it were in the input string...

Comment: In the string '</tbody></table>' and your pattern /(<table )/gi there is not match. I got these message: "Your pattern does not match the subject string." or "1st Capturing group (<table )

    <table matches the characters <table literally (case insensitive)" but the result is empty.

Comment: The third patern message: in string:  `<span class="answer"><span class="answer"><br /></span>` says: "No match groups were extracted.

This means that your pattern matches but there were no (capturing (groups)) in it that matched anything in the subject string." And I need to correct it to find the string. In your last regex, **why** you insert the *brackets*? I am trying to use the regex to replace the string in the command to replace pasted string: `evt.data.dataValue = evt.data.dataValue
          .replace( hArray[k], k );` in CKEditor.